# PHP: $variable in array index doesn't give back result

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
$names = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://country.io/names.json"), true);
$data = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/myIp/country");
echo($names[$data]);
?>
```

`$names` is array of country codes, `$data` is a country code from IP, in my case: IE. I am trying to output full country name but for some reason it doesn't work. However if I type: `echo($names['IE']);` it works fine. What's wrong?

Comment: `$data` is not what you think it is. `var_dump($data)`.

Comment: have you echoed both values to make sure the right values are set? $names should be an assoc array, that has the key of $data. make sure $data is a valid key in $names.

Comment: The first link works fine. I want to test the second one. Provide valid data for this link so we can see what is returned: http://ipinfo.io/myIp/country

Comment: @Len_D second link has your IP address where myIp is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `$data` contains an empty character. [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will remove any empty characters on either side of your string, this code works:

```
<?php
$names = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://country.io/names.json"), true);
$data = trim(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/MyIP/country"));
echo($names[$data]);
?>
```

Also using JSON as @ElefantPhace suggested is *BETTER*

```
<?php
$names = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://country.io/names.json"), true);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/MyIP/json"));
echo($names[$data->country]);
?>
```

Comment: This works perfect, so it was just receiving 3 characters instead of required 2? (2 chars and 1 empty space) so it couldn't find that index?

Comment: No problem :) Also I updated my answer with a json way to solve it, wich is a better way ;)

Comment: Hi, yes, thats the problem :) Also, please accept my answer if you are happy with it :)

Answer (score 1):

try this way, work fine for me:

```
$names = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://country.io/names.json"), true);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io"));
echo($names[$data->country]);
```

Also, you may want to refer to http://ipinfo.io/developers and see why you're probably not getting what you expect

Comment: That outputs country of server where ipinfo is hosted I think, because it gives me United States even though I am from Ireland.

Comment: no it doesn't. Not unless ipinfo.io is hosted right next door to my work. Which it isn't. `var_dump($data)` and see what you get. If you're still not satisfied add `/json` to the end of ipinfo url. and read the documentation on the developers page. It clearly tells you that just using ipinfo.ip returns your address

Comment: it does, IPinfo use your ip adress unless otherwise specified, take a look at my answer :) I expect the OP to want the location of *his* users, not his server :)